# How to generate random numbers with positive z axis?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to generate the 3-Dimensional random numbers, but with the condition that z-component of the array should be positive, x and y can be positive and negative.

I can generate both positive and negative numbers from the following code.

```py
import numpy as np

num = (2*np.random.rand(3)-1)
print(num)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract 1 from only the X and Y values

```
import numpy as np

num = (2*np.random.rand(3)-[1, 1, 0])
print(num)
```